# In WPF, in a project use Struct or Class for model with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mvvm, struct

I'm confused which type I use to create model in project, Struct or Class? There're about ten struct and some collections. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use classes as ViewModel or Model in WPF.

Comment: Thank u, I'm reading.

Answer (score 2):

You should [never create a mutable struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/34397).

View models should always be classes.

Comment: Models is always classes, too?

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie, **don't use structs**. There are subtleties to the way they work that will mess you up.